# how to append log in java using FileHandler

Tags: java, log4j

i am trying to store logs into file using log4j

i tried to create one separate class

```
public class MyLogger {

    FileHandler fh;
    Logger log;

    public MyLogger(String className) {
        log = Logger.getLogger(className);
        try {
            String location = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().replace("%20", " ").replaceFirst("/", "") + "logs.log";
            fh = new FileHandler(location);
            log.addHandler(fh);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error in MyLogger class, method getLogger \n stack trace below \n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void log(Level l, String Message, Object o) {
        log.log(l, Message, o);
        flushStream();
    }

    public void log(Level l, String Message) {
        log.log(l, Message);
        flushStream();
    }

    private void flushStream() {
        fh.flush();
        fh.close();
    }

}
```

i am calling this class each and every time , when i need to log some messages to the file.
it runs fine but it overwrites the old log data each and every time it is called.
how can i append new logs using this code? or is there any other way of logging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another constructor for FileHandler which you can use to explicitly tell FileHandler that you want to ***append*** log. The code is like this:

```
fh = new FileHandler(location, true);
```

Setting the second arguments of this constructor to be ***true*** to append log.